# How to do a jquery ajax call to a subdomain?

Tags: jquery, ajax, subdomain

i could call a page inside the same domain, but its not working when i calling a page in a sub domain due to security issues. what i have to do? help me!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can set the document.domain but if I remember correctly a few browsers (Opera) will not even allow this. I am afraid your answer is to create some sort of proxy on the subdomain that you can talk through

Answer (score 1):

Due to security reasons, most browsers don't allow ajax requests to different domains. So as far as I know, you won't be able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Use a script tag and the response should be a javascript callback.

Ex:

Instead of:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.ajax({
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.field);
    },
    dataType: 'json'
});
</script>
```

Do:

```
<script src="http://sub.domain.com/file"></script>
```

that will result with the following content:

```
data = {'field': 'bleh'}
alert(data.field);
```